# Visualizing Trained Filters

Tags: visualization, neural-networks, convolution

In the first convolutional layer of NetModel "Wolfram..." , the parameters of the filter are 64 (number of filters), and 112x112 (size). The last convolutional layer has 192 55x55 filters.

1. What command can I use to visualise the filters themselves. How can I extract the filters from a trained model (or untrained). Im not interested in the weights of the different nodes. I am also not interested in the visualization of a particular image(dotproduct) after the filter pass.
2. How can I upload my own filter and run the convolution on an image that way?

Thanks